# How to determine the lua version in texlive 2015

Tags: luatex, lua

I look for the **lua** interpreter version in luatex in texlive 2015 ?

Comment: It's in the manual: LuaTeX v0.80 uses Lua 5.2

Comment: Thank you. Witch manual ? Sorry didn't find it.

Comment: The LuaTeX manual (`texdoc luatex`), in the introduction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't trust the manual put

```
print(_VERSION)
```

in `v.lua`

then

```
texlua v.lua
```

will produce something like

```
$ texlua v.lua
Lua 5.2
```

(which was using 0.95 from texlive 2016)

Answer (score 6):

To get the version of Lua and also of other included libraries, you can run LuaTeX with the `-credits` argument:

```
luatex -credits
```

For TeX Live 2021, this shows (after some other information)

```
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with lua version 5.3.6
Compiled with mplib version 2.01
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using 1.2.11

Development id: 7430
```

So TeX Live 2021 has Lua 5.3.6.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the linker will work for some builds of TeX Live, for example those supplied by Linux distribution, since those link Lua dynamically. However, this doesn't work for the official TeX Live binaries since they link Lua statically. An example for TeX Live 2021 with the official Debian packages follows.

```
ldd /usr/bin/luatex | grep lua
    
libtexlua53.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtexlua53.so.5 (0x00007f4b377b8000)
```

The relevant numbers here are `53`, which of course correspond to Lua 5.3. Note that at least on Debian the file it is linking to is contained in the following Debian package:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtexlua53.so.5

libtexlua53:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtexlua53.so.5

apt-cache show libtexlua53
[...]
Description-en: TeX Live: Lua 5.3, modified for use 
with LuaTeX
The Lua 5.3 library as used within LuaTeX.
```

So it links to a copy of Lua 5.3.

However, checking the linker does not require querying a packaging system.